# Как можно установить значение DateTimePicker на значение взятое из sql?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как можно установить значение DateTimePicker (используемого для ввода времени) на значение взятое из sql (тип time)?

Пробую подобный код но в результате какое то не такое время выходит.

```
//Получаем значение столбца с типом time в переменную типа TimeSpan
TimeSpan strTime = reader.GetTimeSpan(time_startIndex);
//Добавляем datetimepicker-у с наименованием time_start время форматированное из TimeSpan
time_start.Value = DateTime.Now.Add(strTime);
```

Comment: А что вам нужно-то? Вы сейчас прибавляете к текущему времени время из БД. Может вам подойдет вместо `DateTime.Now` использование `DateTime.Today`?

Comment: @АндрейNOP мне нужно присвоить значение DateTimePicker-у. Значение берётся из sql столбца типа time. Поменял в коде на DateTime.Today вместо Now - всё хорошо. Спасибо).

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете за начало отсчета *текущую дату и время*: `DateTime.Now` (ради интереса посмотрите результат выполнения строчки `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now)`), а вам нужно использовать начало суток: `DateTime.Today`

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(24);
DateTime dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(timeSpan.ToString());
time_start.Value = dateTime;
```